# How do I add a custom tag to an AWS Batch job submission so that it shows up in CloudWatch status change events?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-batch

For example, for billing purposes, I'd like to pass a tag with information that can be passed to the CloudWatch event.

1. Submit job to AWS Batch with tag "billTo: Jensen121"
2. Cloudwatch fires status change event with the tag
3. Separate application reads the Cloudwatch event, reads the tag, and bills the correct customer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Job tags are not included in the CloudWatch state change event, see [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/batch_cwe_events.html). However, your application can read the job ID from the `detail.jobId` event field and then use [DescribeJobs API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeJobs.html) to get the tags.

Comment: This isn't documented anywhere. Do you know if the missing tags is a bug or a feature? Does make sense to request this from AWS? Not only they do not include the real job tags, they override them with their own, so a more precise answer would be "customer tags are not included". I am super unhappy about the necessity to fetch the job tags via the DescribeJobsAPI, it beats the purpose of an event driven system...

Comment: @Tomáš Linhart Can you help with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73389010/8519380